# Changing formatting of a cell in a different worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, colors, formatting

first time question so apologies if it's not as detailed as it should be. Y'all have been super helpful getting me through my first VBA script so far, but I haven't been able to find a solution to this problem. So here it is!

I'm trying to write a button on worksheet one that when I hit it can change the formatting of specific cells on worksheet 2. The specific code I'm trying is as follows:

```
If Cells(i, 6).Value <> "" And Cells(i, 5).Value <> "" Then
    Worksheets("Info").Range("F5").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End If
```

This if statement is inside a For loop where i is the counter. I'm getting an error 1004, and as far as I can tell it's not letting me select anything in another sheet. When I remove the "Worksheets("Info") bit, the code works fine in Sheet 1, so I'm 90% sure it has to do with trying to modify a cell in a different sheet.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to fully qualify the cells in `If Cells(i, 6).Value <> "" And Cells(i, 5).Value <> "" Then` like you did for `.Range("F5")`, Something like `If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6).Value <> "" And Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5).Value <> "" Then`

Comment: Also check if the value of `i` is a valid  row number

Comment: I modified the code as you suggested but it still doesn't work. It throws the same exception about Worksheets("Info"). i is always a valid number and it doesn't throw any errors on that line. it has a problem with the 2nd line of code, where Worksheets("Info") is present. It is throwing a 1004 error.

Comment: Seems liek your `Worksheets("Info")` is protected?

Comment: That was EXACTLY the problem! You're a hero!

Comment: Glad it is solved :)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to work on multiple sheets you need to identify the sheet on which you want to run a command:

```
With Worksheets("YourFirstSheetName")
    If .Cells(i, 6).Value <> "" And .Cells(i, 5).Value <> "" Then
        Worksheets("Info").Range("F5").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
End With
```

pay attention to the dots before "Cells". They mean that the command (Cells...) will be executed on sheet named "YourFirstSheetName". Instead the other command will be executed on the sheet named "Info"